# In what Ubuntu package are the man pages for the C libraries?

Tags: c, ubuntu

I don't know if this happens to anyone else here, but every time I build a new system, I forget where the man pages for say `limits.h` are in the Ubuntu repos. I've already installed `manpages-dev`. I'll make a point to write this down sometime. Darn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install manpages-posix-dev
```

and to search for stuff with bash completion:

```
andrey@nv:~$ sudo apt-get install manpages [hit tab 1-2 times]
manpages            manpages-de-dev     manpages-es-extra   manpages-fr-extra   manpages-ja         manpages-pl         manpages-posix-dev  manpages-ru
manpages-cs         manpages-dev        manpages-fr         manpages-hu         manpages-ja-dev     manpages-pl-dev     manpages-pt         manpages-tr
manpages-de         manpages-es         manpages-fr-dev     manpages-it         manpages-ko         manpages-posix      manpages-pt-dev     manpages-zh
```

Comment: How exactly does that answer the question?

Comment: @Bill it says what package to install to get man pages

Comment: good spaghetti monster, thank you! Wrote it down...

Comment: @aaa carp: Ah -- I see now. I thought it was asking for filesystem location. +1